# Is a normal matrix satisfying $A^TA=...$ circulant?

Tags: matrices, nonnegative-matrices, circulant-matrices

Let $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ be a [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) matrix such that $a_{ij}\geq 0$ with equality iff $i=j$. Suppose that
$$
A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & \cdots & b\\
b & a & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & a & b\\
b & \cdots & b & a\\
\end{pmatrix},\ where\ b>0.
$$
Does it follow that $A$ is a [circulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) matrix?

Note: There is a partial classification of non-negative normal matrices posted [here](http://www.math.ohiou.edu/~jain/073.pdf), which seems like it can be used to attack this problem.

There is a geometric interpretation as well: both the set of rows and the set of columns of $A$ form equidistant sets of vectors on a sphere, and basic geometry appears to severely restrict the possibilities.

---

[Reposted from math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092185/is-a-normal-matrix-satisfying-ata-circulant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NO**.

Let $A$ satisfy the assumptions. If $P$ is a permutation matrix, then $B:=PA$ satisfies the assumptions too: on the one hand, we have $B^TB=A^TP^TPA=A^TA$. On the other hand (remark that the matrix in the question is permutation-invariant)
$$BB^T=PAA^TP^T=PA^TAP^T=A^TA=B^TB.$$

If the claim is true, we find that $B=PA$ is circulant for every  permutation matrix $P$. We deduce that $a_{ij}$ not only depends upon $j-i$ (modulo $n$), but also depends only upon $j-\sigma(i)$, for every $\sigma\in{\frak S}_n$. We conclude that $a_{ij}$ is constant.

Therefore every matrix $A$ satisfying the assumptions, such that $a_{ij}$ is not constant, provides a counter-example of the form $PA$ for some (many) permutation matrices $P$.

Comment: Very nice. I observed the cyclic invariance but didn't think to extend to arbitrary permutation invariance.

Comment: I am interested in whether the same question holds, but now up to row/column permutation. I have posted the new version here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193803/are-certain-normal-matrices-circulant-part-2

Answer (score 4):

No consider for example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1+\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2}\\1+\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 1\\1 & \sqrt{2} & 0 &1+\sqrt{2}\\\sqrt{2} & 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$