# Are certain normal matrices circulant? (Part 2)

Tags: matrices, permutations, nonnegative-matrices, circulant-matrices

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the family of real [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) matrices $A$ such that $
A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$, for $b>0$.

As a user observed in the solution of [Part 1 of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193510/is-a-normal-matrix-satisfying-ata-circulant/193723), $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under left and right multiplication by permutation matrices. Partition $\mathcal{F}$ into equivalence classes, by writing $A\sim B$ if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by a sequence of row and column permutations.

**Question 1:** Does every equivalence class of $\mathcal{F}$ contain a [circulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) matrix?

**Question 2:** If so, can the circulant matrix be chosen such that $a_{ij}\geq 0$ with equality iff $i=j$?

---

[Part 1 of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193510/is-a-normal-matrix-satisfying-ata-circulant/193723)

[Original question on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092185/is-a-normal-matrix-satisfying-ata-circulant)

[Literature](http://www.math.ohiou.edu/~jain/073.pdf)

There is a natural geometric reformulation of this problem:

*Describe equidistant configurations of $n$ points on an $(n-1)$-sphere, subject to positivity constraints.*

Answer (score 1):

As $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is normal we have $A=Q*S*Q^H$ with $D\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ diagonal and $Q\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ unitary. Let $e=(1\;1\dots 1)^T$, which is an eigenvector of $A^TA=Q*S^H*S*Q^H$ with multiplicity 1 and therefore also of $A$. Let $E$ be the matrix with every entry equal to 1. Note that there exist $\alpha_1, \alpha_2\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha_1 A+\alpha_2 E$ is orthogonal. Hence we can write $A=cE+dR$ with $R$ orthogonal. Vice versa for any $R$ orthogonal with $Re=e$ we can construct a normal $A$ with the desired properties. You can now simply take a generic $R$ to convince yourself that your conjecture is wrong, e.g. take the matrix

```
1.9993    1.0000    1.0273    0.9734
0.9994    1.9999    1.0116    0.9891
0.9737    0.9888    1.9988    1.0386
1.0276    1.0113    0.9622    1.9988
```

(was done in matlab)

Comment: I just want to point out that your reasoning is incorrect: eigenvectors of $A^TA$ need not be eigenvectors of $A$. For instance, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Yes you are right. We also need that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue is 1. I have changed it.